# Find the reason of hangup calls from Asterisk.Net

Tags: c#, .net, asterisk, ivr

We have  IVR system based on asterisk . application programed .Net framework environment by using asterisk.net apies . there is 70% of calls ends without any reason.

I googled and find some sources  but it didn't worked

How can i access to [reasons](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/index.php?page=Asterisk%20variable%20hangupcause) of hang up from asterisk.net?

Is there any way or i should use another solution?

Answer (score -1):

For debug you have use asterisk console and sip debug(if you use sip)

You also can get variable DIALSTATUS which will have call hangup cause AFTER dial command. But that will not help if hangup from callee side.